# sql multithreading application select and delete from a table

Tags: sql, multithreading, client-server, distributed-system

I am developing a multi-thread application (could be considered as a client-server) which processes data. The below is the high level description of the application.

there is a table (with no key and Id field) with many rows in our database server. I have several systems (threads) which read (select) some rows (fixed number of rows) from the table and process them and remove (delete) those rows from the table.

I am looking for a solution for removing (deleting) data without using a temp table; but any ideas with temp storage are welcome.

P.S: By using locks and a temp table, I solved the reading process but I need help on deleting part.

P.S2: One possible solution that Jean said is not removing rows physically from the table. This idea is great but I forgot to mention that this table must be empty after a specific period of time and by using the solution I need to have a system which deletes all the marked rows at the end (which is not possible)

Comment: I suggest you to avoid physical deleting rows for this scenario and create a status column (inserted, processing, deleted).

Comment: Why is it not possible to have a process that would physically delete all rows marked as status 'deleted'?

Comment: Well for that kind of system you ill need to stop it if you want the table to go empty after a period of time. For a real world problem you can stop the system at low demanding hours and clean the table physical deleting all rows marked as deleted. btw if you put a column with the thread id set that status you ill no need to implement locks and temp tables at all (if you are using a read commited isolation level)

Comment: @jean Thanks for your information. for the reading part your solution is nice. we have a temp tables just keeps two counters and reading and writing to the temp table needs ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock.